does this "undo" need to be a full infinitive?
Is this sentence grammatically correct?

First thing he did was undo everything she did.

Does the "undo" have to be a full infinitive? Can it be considered a bare infinitive? Of course, it's very common to speak and write like this. I have a student who believes that it needs to be a full infinitive. I don't know the answer to my question and haven't been able to find one.
Help, please :)

You appear to have answered your own question.  "It is very common to speak and write like this"  The way that native speakers speak and write commonly is the definition of correct grammar.  This is correct grammar.  Can you write an answer now?

Well, yeah ... it's common language usage, but heck, lotsa mistakes are common, yet still widely considered mistakes, just common mistakes. Are you saying I should close this thread down? I'd actually like to see what others have to say about this.

This question is similar to: Explanation of "did was [verb]" structure. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see this question: The easiest thing to do is call for a taxi where one of the answers goes into considerably more detail on why you can omit "to" in constructions like this.

@troysantos,  I'm not saying you should close this thread down. You have only 57 reputation, so you don't have the reputation to close threads.  I'm suggesting that you answer the question, as you seem to already have an answer.  (You can answer your own question. It's quite normal)

The bare infinitive is possible for cases where the subject noun phrase contains DO.  Our case here satisfies the requirement, and hence the infinitive marker is optional:

First thing he did was (to) undo everything she did.

